# Camel exception handling in Grails

Tags: grails, exception, apache-camel

I currently have exception handling being done in an abstract class that all my routes inherit.  Something like this:

```
    onException(SocketException,HttpOperationFailedException)
        .handled(true)
        .maximumRedeliveries(settings.maximumRedeliveries)
        .redeliverDelay(settings.redeliverDelay)
        .useCollisionAvoidance()
        .collisionAvoidanceFactor(settings.collisionAvoidanceFactor)
        .onRedelivery(redeliveryProcessor)
        .log('retry failed, sending to the route failed coordinator')
        .to(routeFailedCoordinator)
```

Now, I want to do some different things based on different response codes.  For all codes other than 200, HttpOperationFailedException get's thrown.  For 4XX codes, I want to send the message on to a failed queue and send an email, if enabled for that particular route.  For all other errors, I want to go through the retry cycle.  Here's what works for the 4XX errors:

```
    onException(HttpOperationFailedException)
        .handled(true)
        .process { Exchange x ->
            HttpOperationFailedException ex = x.getProperty(Exchange.EXCEPTION_CAUGHT, HttpOperationFailedException.class)
            log.debug("Caught a HttpOperationFailedException: statusCode=${ex?.statusCode}")
            ProducerTemplate producer = x.getContext().createProducerTemplate()
            if (ex?.statusCode >= 400 && ex?.statusCode < 500) {
                log.debug("Skipping retries ...")

                producer.send(routeFailedEndpoint, x)

                x.in.body = "Request:\n${x.in.body}\n\nResponse: ${ex.statusCode}\n${ex.responseBody}".toString()
                if (sendFailedEmailEnabled)
                    producer.send('direct:routeFailedEmailHandler', x)
            } else {
                producer.send(routeFailedRetryEndpoint, x)
            }
        }.stop()
```

How do I add code for retrying like in the first code snippet?  I tried using nested choice()...when()...otherwise() clauses and kept getting compile errors.

Anyone had to do something similar?

Here is my code with nested choice()..when()..otherwise() clauses:

```
    onException(HttpOperationFailedException)
        .handled(true)
        .choice()
            .when { Exchange x ->
                HttpOperationFailedException ex = x.getProperty(Exchange.EXCEPTION_CAUGHT, HttpOperationFailedException.class)
                log.debug("Caught a HttpOperationFailedException: statusCode=${ex?.statusCode}")
                if (ex?.statusCode >= 400 && ex?.statusCode < 500) {
                    log.debug("Skipping retries ...")
                    x.in.body = "Request:\n${x.in.body}\n\nResponse: ${ex.statusCode}\n${ex.responseBody}".toString()
                    return true // don't retry
                }

                log.debug("Performing retries ...")
                return false // do attempt retries
            }.choice()
                .when { !sendFailedEmailEnabled }.to(routeFailedEndpoint)
                .otherwise()
                    .multicast().to(routeFailedEndpoint, 'direct:routeFailedEmailHandler').endChoice()
            .otherwise()
                .getParent().getParent().getParent()
                .maximumRedeliveries(settings.maximumRedeliveries)
                .redeliverDelay(settings.redeliverDelay)
                .useCollisionAvoidance()
                .collisionAvoidanceFactor(settings.collisionAvoidanceFactor)
                .onRedelivery(redeliveryProcessor)
                .to(routeFailedCoordinator)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would have to have 2 onException blocks:

- One `onException` with the redelivery settings for redelivery attempts
- Another `onException` that handles the exception and send that email and what you want to do.
- Use an `onWhen` on both `onException` blocks, to return `true` or `false` in either situation based on that http status code. The onWhen is executed by Camel to know which of the onException blocks to use (you can have more, but first to return true is used).

You can find more details on the Camel website, or in the Camel in Action book that has a full chapter devoted to error handling.

Comment: Thanks, Claus.  I'll give i a shot.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, Claus, you pointed me in the right direction.

Basically, as Claus said, use multiple onException blocks, each using an onWhen clause ...

```
    onException(HttpOperationFailedException)
        .onWhen(new Predicate() {
            public boolean matches(Exchange exchange) {
                HttpOperationFailedException ex = exchange.getProperty(Exchange.EXCEPTION_CAUGHT, HttpOperationFailedException.class)
                log.debug("Caught an HttpOperationFailedException: statusCode=${ex?.statusCode}, processing 4XX error")
                return (ex?.statusCode >= 400 && ex?.statusCode < 500)
            }
        }).handled(true)
            .to(routeFailedEndpoint)
            .choice()
                .when { sendFailedEmailEnabled }.process(prepareFailureEmail).to('direct:routeFailedEmailHandler')

    onException(HttpOperationFailedException)
        .onWhen(new Predicate() {
            public boolean matches(Exchange exchange) {
                HttpOperationFailedException ex = exchange.getProperty(Exchange.EXCEPTION_CAUGHT, HttpOperationFailedException.class)
                log.debug("Caught an HttpOperationFailedException: statusCode=${ex?.statusCode}, processing >=500 error")
                return (ex?.statusCode >= 500)
            }
        }).handled(true)
            .maximumRedeliveries(settings.maximumRedeliveries)
            .redeliverDelay(settings.redeliverDelay)
            .useCollisionAvoidance()
            .collisionAvoidanceFactor(settings.collisionAvoidanceFactor)
            .onRedelivery(redeliveryProcessor)
            .to(routeFailedCoordinator)
```